# How to write large amount of data to sd card?

Tags: sd-card, nxp-microcontroller, fatfs

I use LPC54616 to write data on SD Card (FATFS library). The data that are written to SD card are generated in timer callback (~100B per 1ms). I use buffer (uint8_t buffer[6000];) to store this data and they are written to SD card (using f_write function) in main loop. In most cases, it manage to write data without problems (each write contains 100 - 200 Bytes in the buffer), but sometimes it take longer time to write data on SD card and the buffer overflows (more then 6000 Bytes are buffered).

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?
Thank you for response.

Comment: Have two buffers, carry on filling one from the sensor at the same time as writing the other to the SD card with DMA.  When one is full, swap over.  Also, make your buffer a multiple of the SD card sector size.

Comment: Sorry I didnt write it. I use two buffers as you describe. Length of my buffers wasn't multiple of sector size. So I tried to change it and it doesnt't solve this problem. Anyway data are correctly stored in buffers and written to sd card, until buffer overflows. It usually happens every 15 seconds (in my case), but this is not a rule sometimes this time is longer.

Comment: You need to either use multiple threads or a non-blocking driver using DMA.  Reading and then writing to FATFS in the same thread just won't work because it takes more than 1ms to flush its buffers.

Comment: Can you make the buffers drastically larger for a test (like 30-60kB each)? Even at the expense of everything else (so just generate 200 bytes of garbage every ms if needed).